# 'module' object has no attribute 'gethostbyname' error google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, tweepy

Obtained the tweepy example from [here](https://github.com/tweepy/examples).

Tried to run on google app engine launcher version 1.6.3 on mac lion but I get the error

```
'module' object has no attribute 'gethostbyname'

Status: 200 OK Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Cache-Control:
no-cache Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT Content-Length: 0
```

Any ideas as to what might be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, you're trying to use the `gethostbyname` function that's in the socket module, which isn't supported on AppEngine. See the [docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#Pure_Python) (cf. "The Sandbox", emphasis below mine):

> To allow App Engine to distribute requests for applications across
>   multiple web servers, and to prevent one application from interfering
>   with another, the application runs in a restricted "sandbox"
>   environment. In this environment, the application can execute code,
>   store and query data in the App Engine datastore, use the App Engine
>   mail, URL fetch and users services, and examine the user's web request
>   and prepare the response.
>
> An App Engine application cannot:
>
> - write to the filesystem. Applications must use the App Engine datastore for storing persistent data. Reading from the filesystem is
>     allowed, and all application files uploaded with the application are
>     available.
> - **open a socket or access another host directly. An application can use the App Engine URL fetch service to make HTTP and HTTPS requests
>     to other hosts on ports 80 and 443, respectively.**
> - spawn a sub-process or thread. A web request to an application must be handled in a single process within a few seconds. Processes that
>     take a very long time to respond are terminated to avoid overloading
>     the web server.
> - make other kinds of system calls.

Answer (score 0):

Whichever module you think has your `gethostbyname` object does not have it. You don't show your code, or even the full error, so it's impossible to tell you more.